# Is casting an instance of a class to its subclass legal?

Tags: c++, casting, polymorphism

Is casting a class to a subclass of itself without additional data fields well defined?

For example if I wanted to hide certain internal only methods from an end user like in the following.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

// public.hpp
class Talker {
public:
  Talker(std::string text) {
    this->text = text;
  }
  virtual void talk() {
    std::cout << this->text << std::endl;
  }
protected:
  std::string text;
};

// private.cpp
class InnerTalker : public Talker {
public:
  void setText(std::string text) {
    this->text = text;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Talker t("Hello World!");
  t.talk();

  InnerTalker *ht = reinterpret_cast<InnerTalker *>(&t);
  ht->setText("Farewell World!");

  t.talk();

  return 0;
}
```

I have compiled this example and it works as I expect. Printing:

```
Hello World!
Farewell World!
```

However that does not make it well defined behavior.

Thank you in advance for any information you can provide.

Comment: What compiler are you using that produces that output?  On a conforming compiler, `ht` should be null.

Comment: What's the value of `ht` after `InnerTalker *ht = dynamic_cast<InnerTalker *>(&t);`?

Comment: This is my fault I messed up and used the wrong code. I should remake the question using reinterpret_cast.

Comment: Lets say you have `class OuterTalker : public Talker`.  You have a pointer to the base class and initialize to an instance of `OuterTalker`.  What happens when you `dynamic_cast` the {base} pointer to an instance of `InnerTalker`?  Or vice-versa?

Comment: _"I should remake the question using reinterpret_cast."_. That's an easier question.  Dereferencing `ht` is now Undefined Behavior.  Your compiler may detect this and produce all kinds of messy outcomes.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to invalidate existing useful correct answers to the question you typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Notes):

> Performing a class member access that designates a non-static data member or a non-static member function on a glvalue that does not actually designate an object of the appropriate type - such as one obtained through a reinterpret_cast - results in **undefined behavior**:

You can perform the `reinterpret_cast`, but doing *nearly* anything that uses the resulting pointer will result in UB.